# Cyclic iterator in both directions

Tags: javascript, iterator, circular-list

I am trying to make a cyclic iterator that works backwards and forwards. `getNext()` gets the next array item, `getPrevious()` gets the item before the last returned one from `getNext()`. This seems to work, but there must be a better way. How can this be refactored?

```
var cyclicIterator = function (arr) {
    var index = 0;
    var length = arr.length;
    var current;
    return {
        getNext: function () {
            current = arr[index];
            index = (index + 1) % length;
            return current;
           },
        getPrevious: function () {
            index = arr.indexOf(current);
            if (index === 0) {
                index = length - 1;
            }
            else {
                index = index - 1;
            }
            current = arr[index]
            return current;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: What about your current code makes you think it needs improvement? To be honest, I don't see any glaring problems.

Comment: @GregBurghardt there's still things to point out.

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: Please leave the original code intact, now that answers have been posted.  If you'd like further review, post a new follow-up question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any reason why `getPrevious` resorts to using `indexOf`? As far as I can tell, it can only cause problems.

For instance:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = cyclicIterator(array);

iterator.getPrevious();
```

Since `current` is declared but hasn't been assigned a value, this will call  `arr.indexOf(undefined)` and then proceed to subtract 1 from that. I doubt that's going to work out.

Alternatively, I might do this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = cyclicIterator(array);
iterator.getNext(); // current is now 1
array[0] = 2;       // change the first element in the array
iterator.getPrevious();
```

Now, `getPrevious` will call `arr.indexOf(1)` and get -1. And it will then subtract 1 from that. Again, I doubt it'll work out.

I'd also wonder why there's no `getCurrent` function. In fact that's what `getNext` does. It for some reason returns the current index, only incrementing the index afterwards. Meanwhile `getPrevious` decrements the index *before* returning anything.

You also store the length of the array when you receive it, which could lead to some weird stuff if the array is later modified.

For instance:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = cyclicIterator(array);
iterator.getNext(); // index is now 1
array.splice(3);    // clear the array
iterator.getNext();
```

That last call will calculate `2 % 3` which is, well, 2. But that index doesn't exist anymore.

You could simply skip caching the length, but that could still get weird. `getNext` would start skipping places when "looping around", if the array's been truncated after the iterator was created.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = cyclicIterator(array);
iterator.getNext(); // index is now 1
iterator.getNext(); // index is now 2
array.pop();        // remove one item from the array
iterator.getNext();
```

With no caching of the length, the last call will calculate `(2 + 1) % 2` which is 1. But that'll skip index 0.

So I'd simply copy the array, to make sure there's always something to work with.

I'd do this instead:

```
var cyclicIterator = function (array) {
    var index = 0;
    var copy = array.slice(0);

    return {
        getCurrent: function () {
            return copy[index];
        },

        getNext: function () {
            index = ++index % copy.length;
            return this.getCurrent();
        },

        getPrevious: function () {
            if(--index < 0) {
              index += copy.length;
            }
            return this.getCurrent();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: var a = [1,2,3,4]; var d = cyclicIterator(a); in your code d.getNext() returns 2.

Comment: @django Sure, but `getCurrent` will return 1. Question is what you consider "next" and "previous" when you haven't actually done anything yet. If you want, you can replace it with your increment-after solution.

Comment: so in your code i will use first getNext() and getPrevious() to move through items and use getCurrent() to get the current item.

Comment: @django Yes, if you want. I'm not saying my code is the only way to do it, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve the iterator, then call `getPrevious` on it, it fails.

To fix this, you should set current to `arr[0]`.

Consider returning no iterator for empty arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Iterator = (function () {
    function Iterator(toIterate) {
        this.index = -1;
        this.toIterate = toIterate;
        this.length = toIterate.length;
    }
    Iterator.prototype.getNext = function () {
        this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.length;
        return this.toIterate[this.index];
    };
    Iterator.prototype.getPrevious = function () {
        if (this.index < 0) {
            this.index = this.index + this.length;
        } else if (this.index === 0) {
            this.index = this.length - 1;
        } else {
            this.index = this.index - 1;
        }
        return this.toIterate[this.index];
    };
    return Iterator;
})();
```

My last version is this. I have changed it in to a class. As before I am keeping track of the index, to return the next or previous item, in the `index` property so here there is no need for the `var current` current item variable and `index = arr.indexOf(current)`.